# How can I track which blocks players step on the most in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to make a tracker of which blocks players step on the most time? By which blocks I mean the type of block (grass, sand, etc.). I had a nice idea - a survival map where you have to step on some type of block the most to win.

P.S.: I don't want to use mods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pairs of one Repeat and one Chain Command block, one pair for each type of block (or for smaller numbers use good ol' Redstone clocks).

The repeat command block will test if there is a specific block one block under the Player:

```
/execute @e ~ ~ ~ testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:YOUR-BLOCK-ID
```

And the chain one will add one to your scoreboard:

```
/scoreboard players add @a YOUR-BLOCK-ID 1
```

Note:
First you want to create the objective(s) and make them visible:

```
/scoreboard objectives add YOUR-BLOCK-ID dummy

/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar YOUR-BLOCK-ID
```

And you want to create one objective for each block you step on frequently: grass, dirt, stone, cobble, wood logs, stairs, slabs and planks, netherrack, farmland, gravel, sand, air, water, …

---

Example:

First, create the objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add dirt dummy
```

And make it visible:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar dirt
```

Then, in a repeat command block, put this command:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:dirt
```

And if it returnes true, execute this command:

```
/scoreboard players add @a dirt 1
```

---

Now, for each tick you step ( = are above) on one of the blocks you chose to put into your system, it's score on the left of your screen goes up. The blocks with the highest scores go up in the sidebar list.

You can also use good old comparators and redstone clocks to avoid numbers like Dirt: 8294, Grass: 34890

Comment: but then, if you stay in one place the score is huge, even steping just once

Comment: @lois6b Yeah. After some hours of playing (tested it) you get values like Stone: 45000

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek You should have clarified then, that you want to count the process of stepping on a block and not the time spend on a block. Both are valid ways to understand your answer.

Comment: Note that this method is **not** multiplayer-friendly, as the score is being incremented for all players regardless of who is stepping on a block. Making it multiplayer-friendly is very simple, as you'd use `/execute`'s "detect" function, which tests for a block before performing a command (such as `/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:stone 0 /scoreboard players add @a[c=1,r=0] stone 1`).